# It's equivalent event emit angular/vue in blazor?

Tags: angular, vue.js, events, blazor

Is it equivalent of event emit like the underneath in blazor ? :
https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter (in angular)
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html (in vue)

in new blazor syntax @ event name in < > of component (3.0 preview 6)

Comment: Ta question est incompréhensible et ne respecte pas [ask] : profite que je parle français, explique moi rapidement ton souci que je t'aide  !

Comment: Désolé c'est mon premier message je ne savais pas trop dans quel rubrique le poster

Comment: Existe il un equivalent de la fonction event emit (qui est dans angular et vue) pour blazor

Comment: si il y en a un je pense que il faudrait taper @ quelque chose dans la baliste < >

merci

Comment: ça devrait t'aider : https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1355

Answer (score 3):

This work :

Index.razor

```
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" Counter="@Counter" CounterChanged="@CounterChangedFiredEvent" />

<p>Counter: @Counter</p>

@code {
    private int Counter = 1;

    void CounterChangedFiredEvent(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

SuveyPrompt.razor

```
<input type="button" value="Previuos" @onclick="@Previous" />
<input type="button" value="Next" @onclick="@Next" />

@code {
    // Demonstrates how a parent component can supply parameters
    [Parameter] string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    private int Counter { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    Action<int> CounterChanged { get; set; }

    void Next()
    {
        CounterChanged(++Counter);
    }

    void Previous()
    {
        CounterChanged(--Counter);
    }
}
```